Do any Hindu Scriptures talk about Mahavira or any other Jain Tirthankaras?
Jainism, unlike Buddhism, has a cordial relation with Hinduism. Jains even accept that Rama was a divine incarnation. Hindu scriptures do talk about Buddha. I wonder whether Hindu scripture mentions Mahavira or any other Jain Tirthankars.

@Shivadasa So Rishabhadeva was a Hindu ascetic according to Bhagavata?

@Shivadasa Thank you so much for the reference. I read the chapters 3-6 from Skandha V of Bhagavata. This is what I wanted to know. Why don't you write it as an answer? I will accept it as the right answer.

@Shivadasa So basically he was an avatar of Vishnu, just like Buddha. So the bottom line is the founder of Jainism is an avatar of Vishnu according to Hinduism.

There is a possible reference to mahavira in bhagavata purANa 5.15 (as mahavira is considered as son of bharata in his previous birth) :

śrī-śuka uvāca
bharatasyātmajaḥ sumatir nāmābhihito yam u ha vāva kecit pākhaṇḍina ṛṣabha-padavīm anuvartamānaṁ cānāryā aveda-samāmnātāṁ devatāṁ
sva-manīṣayā pāpīyasyā kalau kalpayiṣyanti.
Śrīla Śuka said
The son of Bharata known as Sumati followed the path of Ṛṣabhadeva, but in the Age of Kali some unscrupulous people will imagine him to be
Lord himself. These people, who will actually be atheistic and of bad
character, will interpret the Vedic principles in an imaginary,
infamous way to support their activities. Thus these sinful people
will accept Sumati as Lord and propagate the theory that everyone
should follow the principles of Sumati. In this way they will be
carried away by mental concoction.

Another mention is in padmapurANa Sṛṣṭi-khaṇḍa chapter 13 :

tīrthaṃkarāścaturviṃśattathā taistu puraskṛtāḥ | chāyākṛtaṃ phaṇīṃdreṇa dhyānamārgapradarśakam || 384 ||
384-385. They had adored the twentyfour Tīrthaṅkaras. (For them) Praising with the muttering of incantations the Arhat covered over
with the lord of cobras and showing the path of meditation, heaven was
(quite) at hand or release would come. Which thought is expressed by
them?

Arhat covered with lord of cobras - this might be a reference to parshvanath.

Yes. In Śiva, Padma, Viṣṇu, Liṅga, Matsya Purāṇa-s. To delude the Asuras with false doctrines, Viṣṇu created him in an incident known as Māyāmohaprakaraṇa. Albeit here he is known as Arihat/Arihan.

"Viṣṇu created a delusive teacher called Māyāmoha who created a Māyāśāstra of sixteen lakhs of slokas in Apabhraṁśa, preaching Jina Dharma for misguiding the Asuras. Māyāmoha created four sorts of preachers for the propagation of Jina Dharma. He preached non-violence, forbade Śrauta and Smārta rituals, discarded Varṇāśrama system, created an order for women that resulted in leaving their home and leading the life of nuns."

Here are some excerpts from Śiva Mahāpurāṇa, Section 2.5 - Rudra-saṃhitā (5): Yuddha-khaṇḍa —

तान्रुद्राद्विमुखान्नूनं करिष्यामि सुयत्नतः ।
स्वभक्तिरहिताञ्ज्ञात्वा तान्करिष्यति भस्मसात् ॥

3.54: Viṣṇu said — “Strenuously I shall make them averse to Śiva. Coming to know that they are devoid of devotion to him he will reduce them to ashes."

अरिहन्नाम ते स्यात्तु ह्यन्यानि न शुभानि च ।
स्थानं वक्ष्यामि ते पश्चाच्छृणु प्रस्तुतमादरात् ॥
मायिन्मायामयं शास्त्रं तत्षोडशसहस्रकम् ।
श्रौतस्मार्तविरुद्धं च वर्णाश्रम विवर्जितम् ॥
अपभ्रंशमयं शास्त्रं कर्मवादमयं तथा ।
रचयेति प्रयत्नेन तद्विस्तारो भविष्यति ॥

4.9-11 "Let your name be Arihat. You will have other auspicious names too. I shall assign to you a place afterwards. Now hear with reverence what is relevant to the context. O you who wield Māyā, create a deceptive sacred text of sixteen hundred thousand verses, contrary to Śrutis and Smṛtis wherein Varṇas and Āśramas shall be eschewed. Let that holy text be in Apabhraṃśa lauguage. Let there be emphasis on actions. You shall strain yourself to extend it further."

तच्छ्रुत्वा वचनं तस्य हरेश्च परमात्मनः ।
नमस्कृत्य प्रत्युवाच स मायी तं जनार्दनम् ॥
मुण्ड्युवाच ।
यत्कर्तव्यं मया देव द्रुतमादिश तत्प्रभो ।
त्वदाज्ञयाखिलं कर्म सफलश्च भविष्यति ॥

4.13-14: On hearing the words of Viṣṇu, the Māyā Puruṣa bowed to and replied to Viṣṇu. The shaven-head said:—
"O lord, command me quickly what I shall do. At your bidding, all activities shall be fruitful."

सनत्कुमार उवाच ।
इत्युक्त्वा पाठयामास शास्त्रं मायामयं तथा ।
इहैव स्वर्गनरकप्रत्ययो नान्यथा पुनः ॥
तमुवाच पुनर्विष्णुः स्मृत्वा शिवपदांबुजम् ।
मोहनीया इमे दैत्याः सर्वे त्रिपुरवासिनः ॥
कार्यास्ते दीक्षिता नूनं पाठनीयाः प्रयत्नतः ।
मदाज्ञया न दोषस्ते भविष्यति महामते ॥
धर्मास्तत्र प्रकाशन्ते श्रौतस्मार्त्ता न संशयः ।
अनया विद्यया सर्वे स्फोटनीया ध्रुवं यते ॥
गंतुमर्हसि नाशार्थं मुण्डिंस्त्रिपुरवासिनाम् ।
तमोधर्मं संप्रकाश्य नाशयस्व पुरत्रयम् ॥
ततश्चैव पुनर्गत्वा मरुस्थल्यां त्वया विभो ।
स्थातव्यं च स्वधर्मेण कलिर्यावत्समा व्रजेत् ॥
प्रवृत्ते तु युगे तस्मिन्स्वीयो धर्मः प्रकाश्यताम् ।
शिष्यैश्च प्रतिशिष्यैश्च वर्तनीयस्त्वया पुनः ॥
मदाज्ञया भवद्धर्मो विस्तारं यास्यति ध्रुवम् ।
मदनुज्ञापरो नित्यं गतिं प्राप्स्यसि मामकीम् ॥

4.15-22: Sanatkumāra said:— Saying this he recited the main tenet in the deceptive philosophy. “Heaven and hell are functioning here itself.” Remembering the lotus-like feet of Śiva, Viṣṇu told him again. “These Asuras, the residents of the three cities, shall be deluded. O intellegent one, they shall be initiated by you. They shall be taught strenuously. At my bidding you will incur no sin on that account. O ascetic, no doubt, Vedic and Smārta rites flourish and shine there. But these shall certainly be exploded through this Vidyā. O you with shaven head, you shall go there for destroying the residents of the three cities. Revealing the Tamasika rites, destroy the three cities. After that, O great one, you shall go to the desert region and stay there carrying on your own duties and activities till the advent of the Kali age. When the Kali age begins let your Dharma be revealed. You shall then continue to do so by means of disciples and disciples’ disciples.
At my bidding your cult shall certainly expand. Depending upon my permission and direction you will attain me as your goal.”

एवमाज्ञा तदा दत्ता विष्णुना प्रभविष्णुना ।
शासनाद्देवदेवस्य हृदा त्वंतर्दधे हरिः ॥
ततस्स मुंडी परिपालयन्हरेराज्ञां तथा निर्मितवांश्च शिष्यान् ।
यथास्वरूपं चतुरस्तदानीं मायामयं शास्त्रमपाठयत्स्वयम् ॥
यथा स्वयं तथा ते च चत्वारो मुंडिनः शुभाः ।
नमस्कृत्य स्थितास्तत्र हरये परमात्मने ॥

4.23-25: At the bidding of the lord Śiva transmitted through the thought process, Viṣṇu, the powerful, commanded him thus and vanished. Then the ascetic of shaven head acting in accordance with Viṣṇu’s behest created four disciples of the like form as himself and taught them the deceptive cult. The four disciples had shaven heads and were of auspicious features. They bowed to Viṣṇu, the great soul and stood waiting.

हरिश्चापि मुनेस्तत्र चतुरस्तांस्तदा स्वयम् ।
उवाच परमप्रीतश्शिवाज्ञापरिपालकः ॥
यथा गुरुस्तथा यूयं भविष्यथ मदाज्ञया ।
धन्याः स्थ सद्गतिमिह संप्राप्स्यथ न संशयः ॥

4.26-27: O sage, the delighted Viṣṇu too, who carries out the behests of Śiva spoke to those four disciples. “Just as your preceptor you too will become blessed at my bidding. There is no doubt in this that you will attain good goal.

चत्वारो मुंडिनस्तेऽथ धर्मं पाषंडमाश्रिताः ।
हस्ते पात्रं दधानाश्च तुंडवस्त्रस्य धारकाः ॥
मलिनान्येव वासांसि धारयंतो ह्यभाषिणः ।
धर्मो लाभः परं तत्त्वं वदंतस्त्वतिहर्षतः ॥

4.28-29: The four disciples with shaven heads followed the heretic cult. They had the wicker vessel in their hands. They covered their mouths with a piece of cloth. They habitually wore dirty clothes. They did not talk much. Delightedly they used to speak “Dharma is the great gain, the true essence” and some similar words.

Rig Veda makes a clear reference to Rishabha and Arsishtanami , the Jaina tirthankaras. Rishabha , the first tirthankar of Jainism , is known to be an incarnation of Lord Vishnu. He is mentioned in the Bhagavat Purana and the Rig Veda and Arishtanemi also called Neminatha the 22nd of the 24 Tirthankaras of Jainism a traditional religion of India.While the last two Tirthanakaras may be considered historical personages. Arishtanemi is a legendary figure. Said to have lived 84,000 years before the coming of the next Tirthankara.

This answer could be supported by scriptural references.

You have to add a reference to the Rigvedic verses.

@Amritendu There is none!
